# Regex match exactly n words in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently working on a search which uses regular expressions.

I want to find the words in the text regardless of their position in the text (the text can contain newlines). The regex should match only if **all** words from the search are contained in the text.

Consider the following text:

> This is a test #test which also uses @mentionings

This text should be found if I search for '#test is @mentionings'

I have the following regex which uses lookahead:

`/(?=.*#test).*\n*(?=which.*).*\n*(?=@mentionings.*).*/i`

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: consider using an online regex tester to test regex easily. i recommend http://regex101.com/

Comment: Why not split the task into different regex? Stuffing everything together in a single regex doesn't make it look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookahead that will also search across newlines:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*#test)(?=[\s\S]*which)(?=[\s\S]*@mentionings)
```

**[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB5gJ3/3)**

`[\s\S]` is to match any character including newline.

Comment: You can just drop the `[\s\S]*$` at the end.

Comment: Thanks! But this will also match the text if I only enter 'which' and '@mentionings'.

Comment: Yes that's right, if user enters only `which` and `@mentionings`. Do you want to fail the match if less than 3 words match?

Comment: You wrote **if all words from the search are contained in the text.** and if user enters only 2 words then `which` and `@mentionings` then that's what this reges will do.